# How to pass JSON object to node.js server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a test JSON object as follows

```
{ Id: 100, plugins: [{ Name: 'Test', Version: '2' }] }
```

which I created using

```
var json = {}; 
json.Id =  100;
var plugins = [];
json.plugins = plugins;
json.plugins.push({"Name" : "Test", "Version" : "2"});
```

I have a client side function making an AJAX post request as follows

```
function postJSON() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'features',
      data: json,
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  }
```

I am trying to read this information on my server by just typing `console.log(req)` for now but it does't seem to be getting my json object.

```
app.post("/features", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
})
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can create that object by simply writing `var json = { Id: 100, plugins: [{ Name: 'Test', Version: '2' }] }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you have the `bodyParser()` middleware installed, Express should parse the JSON request payload into `req.body`.

Comment: Thanks Slaks! I made the amateur mistake of forgetting to add bodyParser()

P.S - I am going to dynamically build up the JSON object based on the plugins installed by the user so that was for illustration purposes only

Answer (score 0):

Your creation is wrong.  JSON is a key-value based storage, meaning it has the syntax of a hash.  Try this:

```
var json = {}; 
json['Id'] =  100;
var plugins = [];
plugins.push({"Name" : "Test", "Version" : "2"});
json['plugins'] = plugins;
```

Comment: That is not true; his JSON is perfectly fine.  There is no difference between dot notation and indexer notation.

Comment: Oh, really? The way I was taught, I was told that this was the proper syntax.  I didn't know you could do it two different ways

Comment: You were taught incorrectly.  You should only use indexer notation if you're passing a variable (`someObject[someVar]`).  Otherwise, you should always use `.`.

Comment: Yep Slaks is correct. Even your code results in the same JSON object as mine